# jQuery UI Tabs - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

What am I doing wrong? The tabs will not work at all.

http://pastebin.com/tBsjbZWV

Comment: I don't see the JavaScript that's giving you this error. Please add more details. If that's all there is and you're only using `.tabs()`, then it's most likely because of the issue ariel has mentioned below.

Comment: questions with only links to code are not real questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually there are a couple of problems except for the wrong side of the  slash as ariel noted.
I believe the main problem is you are missing the link for jquery-UI custom css.. (I checked it and it worked fine after the correction)

should be something like:
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" />
you should download the custom css from jquery-ui page

Comment: at what part of the .css file where I can get rid of styling of the tabs?

Comment: I didn't try to edit the css file but is supposed to be quite easy to build it for your custom needs with jquery-ui themeroller.  you can customize it here:http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 1):

You're using an incorrect format for your some of your tags.

Incorrect ----- `<a/>`
Correct   ----- `</a>`

Also, don't forget to include *jquery-ui.css*.